# Learning JavaScript (DOM etc.)

Tags: javascript

I've been writing code for some 15 years in C, C++, various assemblers and recently been involved with Coq, functional languages and some academic PL theory. Yesterday, I looked at JavaScript for the first time and read Crockford's JavaScript: The Good Parts. OK, so syntactically the language is not complicated and it uses standard PL constructs with some ugly legacy quirks.

If I wanted to do something specific, it looked like most stuff I could find online was just code snippets that does this precise thing followed by lots of comments saying "excellent", "thank you" etc. but rarely any discussion of what the example does and why it works.

What are the best resources/books for understanding exactly how the HTML parsing process interfaces with JavaScript? What is the interface from JavaScript to the parsed page in memory? How do you manipulate this data directly? Since modern web pages can add and remove elements without reloading the whole page, there must be ways to add elements to a website after it has been reloaded as well as ways of deleting things and changing them. Where can I learn in-depth how this works? How can I build such elements dynamically based on server-side data? It looks like most sources just tell you how some library does it, but I don't like using a library unless I understand what it does and why.

Another aspect, which is probably another issue would be any resources/books that cover how the VMs actually handle different JavaScript constructs. This would be nice to know for performance reasons.

I also understand if this would get closed for not being very specific. However, my first set of questions is quite specific if written in a shorter way: How does JavaScript interface with the object in memory that represents the rendered page?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> ... how the browser parses html? How does it represent it in memory?
> ... how the VM actually handles different JavaScript constructs
> ```

That's up to the browser vendors. They all offer presentations, blogs and videos that may or may not quench your thirst for knowledge.

When it comes to parsing HTML there are some [specified rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110113/parsing.html) that have to be followed, but the  how is really up to the browser. The same is true for the DOM. There is a [specification](http://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR) that defines the interface (and behavior for that matter), but the how ...

As for the VM: There isn't **the** VM. Every JavaScript engine has it's own one. Some JavaScript engines are [open source](https://code.google.com/p/v8/). As a C++ developer that might be interesting for you. And again: vendor presentations, ...

The best book I can recommend is "Professional JavaScript for Web Developer, 3rd Ed." by Nicholas C. Zakas. It's a library agnostic, extensive and in-depth introduction to JavaScript in the browser.

Comment: Yes, I know that is implementation specific. I was more or less interested in how the stages of the parsing interface with JS, since I assume that must be standardized. I also assume that they use pretty similar translation in the VMs for many constructs, i.e. I can assume that constructs slow in one browser are slow on others and vice versa.

Comment: I'll clarify the question to remove any unnecessary ambiguity...

Comment: V8 developers' blogs are good source of information, for example: http://mrale.ph/blog/

Comment: @EdvardFagerholm No. That's the point. E.g. `Object.create` is really slow in Chrome (if that hasn't changed), whereas `new` is blazingly fast. In some other browsers `Object.create` is faster. Chrome's engine V8 internally creates class constructs for objects, whenever possible. It's **not** safe to assume that others do the same. Recent versions of IE have a decent JS engine, but some operations are ridiculously slow compared to other browsers. The only standard is that of the language.